# Control music playing on iPhone from Computer

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, macbook-pro, music

Is there an app that allows one to control the music playing on my iPhone using the Function keys along the top of my Mac keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried out this application, but I guess for $0.99 it's worth a shot?

[Bowtie](http://isource.com/2010/02/14/bowtie-remotely-control-your-iphone-music-playback-iphone-applications/)

Comment: This does look like a very nice option, but I couldn't find the iPhone app in the App store. Could you point me to the correct place?

Comment: At the article I posted, there is an iTunes link at the bottom I think. ;)

Comment: There is - thank you. Unfortunately, it appears to me that has been removed from the store. Certainly too bad.